# How to convert unicode QString to an std::string?

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, std, qstring

I need convert a `QString` to an `std::string`. However, if this string contains unicode symbols, I get `????`. How can I convert the string with the proper encoding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

How did you try to convert the string so far?

According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#toStdString) `std::string QString::toStdString ()` should convert the unicode-data to an ascii-string

But be warned that you loose special-chars which ascii can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

According to Qt documentation, QString::toStdString internally uses toAscii() function: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toStdString

Basically, you'll need to make your own converter function that would use QString::toUtf8() instead.